# Numpy and Scipy for IronPython using IronClad....installation

Tags: python, linux, numpy, ironpython, ironclad

I have installed IronPython and would like to use Numpy and Scipy by using Ironclad. However i am unable to do it for Linux. If any one has done this before could he let me know the steps he has taken

Comment: Detailing where you are stuck helps us in providing accurate answers. What did you try / what went wrong?

Comment: not been able to do as mentioned in http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/...when i import ironclad i get a error SystemError: CreateMutex

Comment: Your problem might be related to this: http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/issues/detail?id=13&can=1&q=createmutex which means you're probably now running this: http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/issues/attachmentText?id=13&aid=1625327799273879707&name=Unmanaged.cs. Try running `locate` to see if you have all `.so` libraries installed (you might need to run `sudo updatedb` first.

Comment: the part you gave me is for the source while i am trying on the binary version...http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/..the intro part is not working